# Delete a tableview cell by tapping the red minus icon in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to delete the tableview cell right away without the confirmation of red "Delete" button press when user clicks the red minus icon. 
Steps 1. Hit edit button > red minus icon appears > hit the minus icon >> row deleted without showing the red "Delete" icon.

Comment: Implement delete by swipe left then.

Comment: i want to use the confirmation of delete as hitting the red minus icon. So i need to follow the exact steps mentioned above.

Comment: You are contradicting your question: **I want to delete the tableview cell right away without the confirmation of red "Delete" button press when user clicks the red minus icon**.

Comment: I just want to delete the cell by tapping on the minus icon instead of the default "Delete" button. Sorry if i confused you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the work you want.

```
- (nullable NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViews titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
[arrOutputRecords removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[tableViews deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                  withRowAnimation:YES];

[_tableView reloadData];

return @"";
}
```

Comment: May be you misunderstood.. I don't want to show the delete button, just hit the red minus icon, item deleted, no need to press the delete button.

Comment: Do not call `reloadData` after `insert/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. The insertion/deletion method takes care of updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add these methods in your class:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if (self.tableView.editing) {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

 alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
   { action -> Void in
     arr.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
     tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
   })
   self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Added this method. But still doesn't work.- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: you have to call `tableView.setEditing = true` from somewhere

Comment: so as soon as it delete item from table write `tableView.setEditing = false`

Comment: May be you misunderstood.. I don't want to show the delete button, just hit the red minus icon, item deleted, no need to press the delete button.  tableView.setEditing = false is not going to meet my requirement and it didn't.

Comment: ohh ok. Yes I misunderstood. I will do some digging for what u want

Comment: In that case I think u need to customize this functionality..I guess